# Why am I logged out of Galaxybase's visualization platform after not using it for a while?

Tags: graph-databases

I was usually dropped out from Galaxybase's visualization platform (called galaxybase studio) after not using it for about one day and it is a little bit annoying. Are there any settings I can make to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the token has expired and you need to log in again to get the token verification.

The current mechanism is that if a request is continuously sent, the token expiration time will be refreshed in real time.

The token expiration time is calculated from the time when no request is sent, and if the token expires, the token will be detected again, and then the user will be forced to log out and log in again if the token needs to be retrieved.

The valid time of token is assignable: **Galaxybase studio (the visualization platform) - System Settings - System Parameter Settings - Account Session Timeout Period(s).**